# How can pyarrow be used to write a pandas DataFrame as Parquet 2.0 containing dates?

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

We'd like to write a pandas `DataFrame` to Parquet 2.0 (i.e. wherein timestamps are int64) via pyarrow. The `DataFrame` contains timestamps. The output Parquet should be "flavored" as Spark. The `DataFrame` is casting the timestamps via `pandas.to_datetime`. A table is constructed like so: `table = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(dataframe)`. Finally the `pyarrow.parquet` module is used to write the table: `pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, 'foo.parquet', flavor='spark', compression='SNAPPY')`. The resulting Parquet utilizes the deprecated int96 formatting. So what's the correct method for coercing to Parquet 2.0 using these tools?

Comment: Try adding `version=2.0` to `write_table` so it is `pyarrow.parquet.write_table(table, 'foo.parquet', flavor='spark', compression='SNAPPY', version='2.0')`

Comment: That still results in an int96 @Pace.

Comment: Ah, digging further it appears that is a consequence of `flavor='spark'`.